# Leading/Trailing Space to Superview not working for Table View Cell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

[My UI in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u6Wd.png)

[Result in the Xcode simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZZy3.png)

Constraints for the left side (navy table view cell):

- Trailing Space to: Superview
- Width equals: 187.5
- Bottom Space to: Superview
- Height equals: 319
- Leading Space to: PollText1 (the other turquoise table view cell)
- Top Space to: Poll Username (username label on top of the table view cells)

Comment: I suggest you wrap everything in your tableviewcell inside an UIView.